Parse txt file on basis of occurrence of a tag in Linux
I am trying to parse a txt file containing xml "messages"in linux, something like this
<Document abc xyz .....> <hji> xyz </hji> </Document> <Document abc xyz .....> <hji> xyz </hji> </Document> <Document abc xyz .....> <hji> xyz </hji> </Document> <Document abc xyz .....> <hji> xyz </hji> </Document> and so on 

The code will read file, extract each section from <Document .....> till </Document> and put each section into a separate file.
My code for this is as below
input_file="input_file.txt"

# Extracting Document parts
sed -n '/<Document/,/<\/Document>/p' "$input_file" > temp_output.txt

# Splitting into Different Files
csplit -f output -b %d.txt -z temp_output.txt '/<\/Document>/' '{*}'

# Cleaning up temporary files
rm temp_output.txt 

However, this code is extracting several xml messages into one file, particularly the ones with no line break. Could someone suggest what can be rectified in the above code?

Any reason you can't use an XML parser such as xmlstarlet or xmllint or even one of the XML parsers available for python in light of your user namer?

You could use perl to extract all the strings running from <Document to </Document> and write to files:
perl -l -0777 -ne '
  for (m{<Document[\s>].*?</Document>}gs) {
    open F, ">", $f = sprintf("%04d.txt", ++$n) or die "$f: $!\n";
    print F $_
  }' < "$input_file"

That assumes there are no nested <Document>s and that the file is small enough to fit in memory.
